# What is the difference between SetParametersAsync and OnParametersSet method in Blazor lifecycle?

Tags: parameters, blazor, parameter-passing

I have created one Blazor web application. In that when the child component receives the values from the parent component using a [parameter], both OnparametersSet and SetparametersAsync methods are triggered.
I just want to know the difference between OnparametersSet and  SetparametersAsync methods.
When SetParametersAsync method gets triggered and when the OnParametersSet method gets triggered?

Comment: But OnParametersSet is also having async version right OnParametersSetAsync. OnParametersSet will be executed immediately after SetParametersAsync. Then what is the difference between SetParametersAsync and OnParametersSet methods?

Comment: You handle `OnParametersSet` as if it was an event. It fires after your `[Parameter]s` have been set. You may redefine `SetParametersAsync` if you want to customize how parameters must be applied to the component. It is called by the framework before the `[Parameter]s` are set, and [controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#when-parameters-are-set-setparametersasync) how they are set.

Comment: That I understand from the documentation. [SetParameterAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.setparametersasync) is called before values in setted in properties. [OnParametersSetAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.componentbase.onparameterssetasync) is called after values in setted in properties.

Comment: The complete lifecycle is explained here, should help - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 5):

`SetParametersAsync()` is called first when a component is (re-)rendered. The base implementation actually sets the parameters.

`OnParametersSet()` is also called every time a component is (re-)rendered but after SetParametersAsync() and after OnInitialized{Async}().

You override `SetParametersAsync()` when you want to manually set the parameters. This can be an optimization. But be careful, do not await anything here.

You override `OnParametersSet()` to react to the new parameter values. Like fetching new data. The base implementation does nothing.

This picture is from the docs but it is wrong where it places SetParametersAsync in the "-First render only-" section:

[image]